# Scrolling image on top of background image not moving

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a transparent image scrolling on top of my background image. I followed the tutorial located here: http://www.kudoswebsolutions.com/blog/jquery_scrolling_background/demos.html

I altered the code a bit since I only need the overlay to scroll, instead of the background itself. Currently, I can see my overlay image on top of the background image, but it isn't moving.

Think of my background image being wine, and the overlay image being moving bubbles.

In the original tutorial, the background is moving and it's overlayed with the image (the bubbles). The change I've (tried to) made is letting the overlay scroll instead of the background. Even though I've changed the values from `$('#container').css("background-position", "50% " + offset + "px");` to `$('#overlay').css("background-position", "50% " + offset + "px");`, the image doesn't move. I left everything else the same in the .js-file.

Also, in the tutorial the overlay div is encapsulated within the container div. As you can see, I've now encapsulated the body-div within the overlay-div in my own HTML file. Also, I've changed the position of the overlay in the CSS file to `relative`.

My code:

HTML-page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/assets/styles.css" type="text/css"  />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="overlay">
<div class="body">
<div class="header">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS-file:

```
body {
        background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
        width: 1104px;
        height: 976px;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        font-family: Verdana;
}

#overlay {
        position:relative;
        width:899px;
        height:858px;
        background:url("../images/overlay.png");
}
```

And my JS file:

```
$(function() {
    // Define the height of your two background images.
           //The image to scroll
       var backgroundheight = 1000;

    // Create a random offset for both images' starting positions
        offset = Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random()* 2001));

    function scrollbackground() {
                //Ensure all bases are covered when defining the offset.
        offset = (offset < 1) ? offset + (backgroundheight - 1) : offset - 1;
        // Put the background onto the required div and animate vertically
        $('#overlay').css("background-position", "50% " + offset + "px");
        // Enable the function to loop when it reaches the end of the image
        setTimeout(function() {
            scrollbackground();
            }, 100
        );
    }

    // Initiate the scroll
    scrollbackground();

    // Use the offset defined earlier and apply it to the div.
        $('#overlay').css("background-position", "50% " + offset + "px");
});
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar so we can play with it in realtime. Or provide all relevant `html` code, not just the snippet you have provided above. Not many are going to bother reading through the whole tutorial just to setup a workbench to test your code! :)

Comment: Working on it, good tip!

Comment: Also explain what changes you have actually done to the code from what was provided from the tutorial. This will help someone target their attention to the deserving bits.

Comment: Can I add images to fiddle? I also edited my question to include more information on my changes.

Comment: Also, my HTML code should be complete as it is since the images are loaded from the CSS-file.

Comment: you could upload the images to something like http://imgur.com/ (that's what StackExchange uses!) and then hotlink them in your fiddle code.

Comment: My JS source was incorrect and unchanged from the tutorial. *sigh*. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'll have to wait two days for that, I'm afraid. But I will, and I hope my question + answer become usefull to others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My links to my JavaScript resource where faulty. If people are interested how this concept works, check out my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YuBpA/. Original tutorial comes from http://www.kudoswebsolutions.com/blog/jquery_scrolling_background/demos.html, make sure to take a look there.